# If my website is behind cloudflare, is it possible for someone to find out the real servers IP adress?

Tags: cloudflare

So if I run website on VM, and I use cloudflare, can someone find out the real IP address of my server?

And if they can, is there anything I can do to make it impossible?

And vice versa.. of someone starts probing my VM, is there anyway for them knowing my IP adress, to find out what websites are on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible. Some tips to [reduce the probability someone can find your IP address](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170166-General-website-security-guidelines).